# how to use jwt token from node js in laravel tymon/jwt-auth

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, jwt

I create a login in express js with JWT authentication.

then i have another service which use laravel 8.68.1,
on laravel i use tymon/jwt-auth as application support handle jwt token.

but I'm having problems with authentication in larvel which uses the jwt token from expressjs. and the resulting response is 401 Unauthorized

payload jwt from xpressjs:

{
"sub": 7,
"iss": "http://localhost/api/auth/login",
"iat": 1683616190,
"exp": 1683644990
}

and requre claim from tymon/jwt-auth

```
'required_claims' => [
        'iss',
        'iat',
        'sub',
    ],
    
/* 'required_claims' => [
    'iss',
    'iat',
    'nbf',
    'sub',
    'jti',
], */
```

can you give me a suggestion or a solution.

Comment: *I'm having problems with authentication in larvel* - then please let us know what exact problem you have. Edit the question to add details.

Comment: ok, i'm sorry. my english is not good.


"but I'm having problems with authentication in larvel which uses the jwt token from expressjs. and the resulting response is 401 Unauthorized"